# Prevent crossing of arrows in dagre-d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3, dagre

I have recently started using dagre-d3 and I found it neat until I needed to do larger graphs. The algorithm leads to these kind of situations:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHgqm.png)

As seen above, the two nodes should be connected by two arrows. However, Dagre's algorithm decides to cross them, making the graph a mess.

Any ideas on how to prevent it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow! Please add relevant code to your question. How are you generating the graph?

Comment: Your image doesn't *really* describe the complexity you're dealing with in your modeling - however, the best built-in library utility is probably the [style and attribute](http://www.samsarin.com/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/style-attrs.html) portion. You can always manipulate using D3, or maybe, Dagre isn't best suited for your project.

Comment: I did not put the full image as it is way too large. If anyone is interested here is half of it:

https://i.imgur.com/71OyEiE.png



The code is just the demo version with more nodes added to it. I believe Dagre-D3 is not optimized for such large graphs  as wahwahwah says.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that Dagre-D3 does not have an optimized algorithm to deal with large data files. I ended up using [viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/) which is basically Graphviz in JavaScript.